# Extra square bracket ([) when uploading image

Tags: support, markdown, uploader

I was making a post on the gamedev meta and after I posted it I noticed that between the Header and the image I first uploaded there was a trailing `[` and I went to edit the post and remove it, only...

> [image: Weird []

...it doesn't actually exist, except as part of the image embed markup.

Blue to notate the original image (and scribble over the original freehand circle).

Comment: As a note, the testing announcement post states that turning it off isn't immediate. I think it's even in bold. If you want to compare, use an incognito window and don't log in. 

Comment: I totally missed that >..> Also, that's a comment for [that post](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2751/75627).

Comment: Images uploaded via the uploader are supposed to be linked. It appears that there's a missing bracket after `on`. Since that isn't the default image description, I assume you deleted that bracket by mistake when typing up the description.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog ...that's exactly what it is. Doh. Thanks. I couldn't see it because I just don't actually understand how the markup for images *works.* ;)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog that's worthy of an answer, along with retagging this to [tag:support].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you're missing a `]` before the first `[1]` (which you presumably deleted by mistake).

`[text][number]` is a link.

`![text][number]` is an inline image.

Putting the two together (by replacing the "text" part of the link with an image, to make an image with a link) gives you `[![text][number]][number]`.

In your case, apart from the extra `[`, this would mean the image isn't also a link, as the text of the image is `text[number]` instead of just `text`, and the last `[number]` is consumed for the image, and is thus not available to make a link.

You can also use the alternative form `[text](url)` in any of the 3 cases above (although in the last case that would require the URL appearing twice rather than just having it once with 2 references to it).

Comment: That's a great breakdown of how the image markdown works. Thanks!